# How do I ask the arguments?

Tags: c, string, arguments

I would like to save the number of the argument in a block or count.
Can't automatically ask the argument number?

```
void format(int max, ...)
{
    va_list arg_ptr;
    int args;
    char* day;
    va_start(arg_ptr, max);
    args = 0;
    while (args < max)
    {
        day = va_arg(arg_ptr, char*);
        printf("Day: %s\n", day);
        args++;
    }
    va_end(arg_ptr);
}

format(2, "Sat", "Sun");
```

Comment: Setting aside the fact that it's unclear what you're asking, no modern C++ code will use varargs. In C++ we use templates. varargs is for C, not C++.

Comment: So how do I put it into char array? The server sends the packet to the client and can read the argument.

Comment: You will have to parse the formatting string yourself, and extract the next parameter, every time a placeholder for the formatting operation is encountered (of course, making sure to check for overflows). You will have to write all the code to do this complicated work by yourself. There is no library function to do it for you, automatically. You will have to write all the code to do this, yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No, impossible. There is no way to get the number of arguments passed via `va_args` at runtime. If it did exist, the standard library `printf` would surely use it by now to catch common programming bugs including several security exploits.

Comment: So how do I put it into char array? The server sends the packet to the client and can read the argument.

Comment: @TamásSipos: Impossible to say. There's not enough information in your question.